# Trait typedef changes in different contexts for the "same" template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, type-traits

Sorry for the large source - I narrowed it as far as I thought would be sensible for the description of the problem.

I try to (recursively) extract the "content type" of any container (identification using specific trait or sfinae traits respectively).

What I want to achieve is `content_type<vector<A<int>> == int` [if `has_content` and `content_trait` say that `A` has content and define the content type].

The following program emits (MSVC)

```
content_type<struct A<double> (3627049818)> = double(2699759368)
content_type<struct A<double> (3627049818)> = struct A<double>(3627049818)
0 1 1
```

Which basically means that my trait is delivering "different" (but the same?!) content types in different contexts for the same type.

(Note: The identification of `std::vector` as content-containing type is delivered by traits checking for begin/end or subscript[]/size() in the original program.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cstddef>

template<class T> struct content_trait;

template<class T> struct has_content : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct has_content<std::vector<T>> : std::true_type{};

namespace detail
{
  template<class T, bool has_content = content_trait<T>::value>
  struct content_helper { typedef T type; };
  template<class T>
  struct content_helper<T, true>
  { typedef typename content_trait<T>::type type; };
  template<class T>
  struct content_vec_helper
  {
    typedef decltype(*(std::declval<T&>().begin())) value_type;
    typedef typename content_helper<value_type,
      has_content<value_type>::value>::type type;
  };
}

template <class T> struct content_trait
{ typedef typename detail::content_vec_helper<T>::type type; };

template<class T> using content_type 
  = typename detail::content_helper<T, has_content<T>::value>::type;

template<class T> struct A {};
template<class T> struct content_trait<A<T>> { typedef content_type<T> type; };
template<class T> struct has_content<A<T>> : std::true_type { };

template<class T> char const * nameof() { return typeid(T).name(); }
template<class T> std::size_t hashof() { return typeid(T).hash_code(); }
template<class T>
void check()
{
  std::cout << "content_type<" << nameof<T>() << " (" << hashof<T>() << ")";
  std::cout << "> = " << nameof <content_type<T>>();
  std::cout << "(" << hashof<content_type<T>>() << ")";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<class T, class U>
void same()
{
  std::cout << std::is_same<T, U>::value << " ";
  std::cout << (hashof<T>() == hashof<U>()) << " ";
  std::cout << (typeid(T) == typeid(U)) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  typedef A<double> a_type;
  typedef detail::content_vec_helper<std::vector<A<double>>>::value_type b_type;
  check<a_type>();
  check<b_type>();
  same<a_type, b_type>();
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  system("pause");
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

#### So ...

Why does `is_same<A,B>::value` say `0` where `typeid(A) == typeid(B) && typeid(A).hash_code() == typeid(B).hash_code()`?
And why isn't `content_type<std::vector<A<double>>> == double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you have

```
detail::content_vec_helper<std::vector<A<double>>>::value_type == A<double>&
```

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

> 1) [..]. If type is a reference type, the result refers to the referenced type.

As you compare `T` with `T&`, the `typeid` *comparison* is identical, but the types are different.

You may change `content_vec_helper` to:

```
template <class T> struct content_vec_helper
{
    typedef typename std::decay<decltype(*(std::declval<T&>().begin()))>::type value_type;
    typedef typename content_helper<value_type, has_content<value_type>::value>::type type;
};
```

to have

```
detail::content_vec_helper<std::vector<A<double>>>::value_type == A<double>
```

Comment: upped earlier, accepted now cause tested and working :) I didn't know that typeid does not recognize references.